# Posting JUnit reports to Slack

Tags: junit, junit4, slack, cucumber-junit, junit5

Is there any way we can post JUnit results `**/TEST-*.xml` to Slack. I have tried all possible ways but couldn't able to solve the issue.

Comment: https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload ?
Definitely not a junit-related question.

Comment: Thanks @Sormuras tried this already. Didn't work for me

Comment: "didnt work for me" isnt working for us. How are we supposed to understand *why* it doesn't work for you? What exactly did you try; and more importantly: why doesnt it meet your requirements? In essence, you are asking "can someone help me", and guess what: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 3):

JUnit itself cannot do this. It is not the goal of this framework to publish things. For such purpose you would use a build script or tool like

- Maven - https://github.com/moacyrricardo/maven-slack
- Gradle - https://github.com/Mindera/gradle-slack-plugin

Or even more convenient a CI tool like

- Jenkins - https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin
- TeamCity - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/teamcity?correctionAllowed=true&search=slack
- Travis CI - https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#Configuring-slack-notifications